# TypeError: Cannot read property 'accessToken' of undefined in k6 tests

Tags: json, postman, web-api-testing, k6

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'accessToken' of undefined
```

I am have used postman to test an API using bearer token and it was running fine. However when I convert it to k6 i am unable to run the accessToken.

Here's my code

```
// Auto-generated by the postman-to-k6 converter

import "./libs/shim/core.js";
import "./libs/shim/urijs.js";

export let options = { maxRedirects: 4 };

const Request = Symbol.for("request");
postman[Symbol.for("initial")]({
  options,
  environment: {
    BASE_URL: "cannot share",
    AUTH_URL: "{{BASE_URL}}/login",
    TOKEN: ""
  }
});

export default function() {
  postman[Request]({
    name: "POST_Authentication",
    id: "5d152f56-5305-4be2-a790-1294612da9db",
    method: "POST",
    address: "{{AUTH_URL}}",
    data:
      '{\r\n\t"username": "example@gmail.com",\r\n\t"password": "hidden"\r\n}',
    post(response) {
      postman.setEnvironmentVariable("TOKEN", pm.response.json().accessToken);
    }
  });

  postman[Request]({
    name: "Get - Product by ID",
    id: "e3462baf-8423-4c5b-8421-6232c8a59445",
    method: "GET",
    address: "{{BASE_URL}}/module/all",
    auth(config, Var) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${pm[Var]("TOKEN")}`;
    }
  });
}
```

I did try to change the `pm.response`, but not able to achieve the resolution.

Comment: What is `pm`, what is `pm.response`, what is `pm.response.json()`? Do they contain the values you'd expect? It sounds like your response might be empty

Comment: I have used postman to save the token inside the environment variable using the command postman.setEnvironmentVariable("TOKEN", pm.response.json().accessToken)

Comment: But that line is failing, probably because `pm`, `pm.response` is null. Where is `pm` defined/assigned? I'm not seeing the assignment